How can I achieve UNORDER_ACKNOWLEDGMENT using Spring JMS
In my spring application, there are a few listeners. I've noticed that when deploying the application, I see the following message pretty rarely:
Rejecting received message because of the listener container having been stopped in the meantime. 
And can see the DLQ grow. The current ack mode is set to the default (so it's auto ack). I want to change this to client ack and have control over the acknowledgement.
I've got the following beans configured:
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setErrorHandler(this::handleError);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTemplate(sqsConnectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public AmazonSQS buildAmazonSqs() {
    return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
}

@Bean
public SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory(AmazonSQS amazonSQS) {
    return new SQSConnectionFactory(
            new ProviderConfiguration().withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(1),
            amazonSQS);
}

But after doing a few experiments, what i've noticed is that even when message.acknowledge(); is not executed on the receiving object in my JMSListener, the message is still popped from the queue. It does not get back on the queue. And after looking at datadog and seeing the trace, i can see behind the scenes that the message is being deleted from the queue. Even replacing Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGMEN with SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE, there is no difference.
The reason why i want to use UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGMENT is because using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT will ack preceeding messages as described here.
Would i essentially have to use @SqsListener instead of Spring's @JmsListener? If not, then how can i prevent Spring from ack'ing the msg without calling acknowledge() on the receiving message object?
